# Unable to get Json from Controller into View

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I am in the process of learning how to pass Json to my views from the controller and created a simple page with a button that will display a name in an alert box. The controller creates the name and passes it back to the view. When the button is pressed, I can see that the 3 lines of code debug fine, although, in my Ajax call, neither the success or error is ever called. Can someone shed a little light. Thanks.

My Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetNames() {
    Person p = new Person();
    p.FirstName = "Mic";
    p.LastName = "Muffin";         
    return Json(p);
}
```

My View

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        alert("Hello");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "Home")',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            sucess: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Not Good");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ActionResult` to a `JsonResult`. The Ajax callback is called `success`.

Comment: Thanks. That was a saturday morning typo